# Parsing JSON using C?

Tags: c, json

There are several C libraries available for parsing JSON, that will compile on Linux. Which library would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop:

For the project in question, we ended up going with [cJSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjson/). We chose this one from the list of C libraries linked from [json.org](http://json.org/). Per the homepage, cJSON is:

> An ultra-lightweight, portable, single-file, simple-as-can-be ANSI-C compliant JSON parser, under MIT license.

This happened to be a good fit for the particular project at hand, and the library worked out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen [`YAJL`](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/) used with `MGTwitterEngine` (Mac/Cocoa), so I assume it is ok.

I haven't done much with it apart from compiling it and pointing `MGTwitterEngine` on Mac to its library/header files.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the list at [json.org](http://www.json.org). There are several C libraries for JSON.

Comment: About the marked answer: the SO community frowns upon questions being answered by the same person(s), granted that in this case it may have been unintentional. Also please note that SO may remove reputation points for answering your own questions.

Comment: Whatever gave you that idea? [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the [Help] starts with "Yes!"

Comment: Answering your own question has always been encouraged, although I did not set out to in this case. I did link to json.org from that answer, though.

Comment: Just pointing this out what we already know (and I stated this is probably unintentional by the OP), see this meta SO discussion link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question there are just certain things to keep in mind...