# C: JSON processor

Tags: c, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276728/parsing-json-using-c)

What's is the best C library for processing JSON? There are several listed at http://www.json.org/.

Comment: Community wiki? That sounds pretty subjective to me.

Answer (score 1):

I vote [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/). It's easy to work with, and highly customizable.